# SQL Server : check if the boundaries of two geographies/geometries meet each other

Tags: sql, sql-server, geometry, geography

I want to check if the boundaries of the two geography/geometry meet/connect/touch each other.

In the below diagram:

- For case 1 - Used `STContains()` to check B is within A
- For case 2 - Used `STOverlaps()` to check B and A overlaps/intersects
- For case 3 - Tring `STDiatance()` but it seems to give 0 when `STOverlaps()` results in 0 which is incorrect. It should return some value when `STOverlaps()` returns some value.

How do I confirm if both the boundaries touch each other?

[image]

Comment: I think you want `STIntersects()` instead:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/stintersects-geometry-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Earlier I had used STIntersects but it always gives 1 even when only boundaries touch. I want to ignore when boundaries touch and take only proper intersected records

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a very specific definition of overlapping.  What you want to do starts with `STIntersection()`.

You are then doing to have to check if the result is what you want.  I'm not sure what that is:

- Perhaps that the dimension is 1 (or greater).
- Perhaps that there is more than one point.
- Perhaps that the length of the intersection is greater than some threshold.

Answer (score 0):

It might seem that you can get what you want by taking the `STArea` of the `STIntersection` :

```
declare @circle1 geometry =  geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT (0 0)', 0).STBuffer(1);

declare @leftHalfPlane geometry = geometry::STGeomFromText('POLYGON ((0 100, -100 100, -100 -100, 0 -100, 0 100))', 0);

declare @leftcircle1 geometry = @circle1.STIntersection(@leftHalfPlane);
declare @rightCircle1 geometry = @circle1.STDifference(@leftHalfPlane);

declare @inter geometry = @leftcircle1.STIntersection(@rightcircle1);

select @inter
select @inter.STArea();

select @leftcircle1.STIntersects(@rightCircle1);
```

Here we define a left and right semicircle and see that the `STArea` of their intersection is zero, although `STIntersects` says they intersect.

However, if you have any kind of *real* data, you will almost certainly find that irregular regions (such as you've drawn in your case 3) which *appear* to touch with no overlap in fact have a tiny portion in common. MMuch like with comparing floating-point numbers, you will probably want some tolerance on your area test, rather than simply 'is zero' / 'is not zero'.